# Download and Edit HTML Source File in Word and Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Have tried to solve this myself for a while but I think I need some help from someone with more experience.

There is a website with time-series data displayed in a graph: https://electionbettingodds.com/WIN_chart_maxim_lott_john_stossel.html
I am trying to get this data downloaded and neatly squared away in excel so I can recreate the graph.

The data points for the chart are contained in the source html file for the webpage, all on one line.  The categories (for one time period) are broken up by commas and the time periods are broken up by the word "new".  I am looking to download the HTML file with word, then insert paragraph breaks on the word "new", then take the broken up lines into Excel where I can separate the categories of data on the commas. (Excel wont accept one super long string of data, but Word will.)

How can I:

1. Download the HTML source into word  (https://electionbettingodds.com/WIN_chart_maxim_lott_john_stossel.html)
2. Only keep the single (very large) line of the code (Line:66) with all the data entries
3. Divide it up on the word "new" with paragraph breaks
4. Take the Word content and copy it over into excel
5. Separate the data entries on the commas.  (I think I can handle recording a macro for this part).
6. Make this so that every time I open excel it updates or at least is easy to replicate again when new data comes in.

Thank you very much for all your help!!!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do it in Excel? You can probably do that while sweating blood, but this would be super easy in Ruby with its Net and Nokogiri gems.

Comment: I need to continue to use the data in excel, to manipulate for my research.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... So noone here is likely to answer this for you.

But, there is another way. Answer it yourself.

All you need is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISmZVK0GGFU&list=PL6OYc4rwKjcOu3UL7LYpvO_S2waYO-hVU

Once you have had a crack, come back and have a chat with what doesn't work :)